# How to hide the scroll of the browser before hover the menu

Tags: html, css

My only problem is that. I have css drop down menu. Before i hover on it i see a scroll bar. When i made a debug i see that there is hidden `li` elements. But when i hover on the menu the scroll bar is gone. It seems that `li` elements are getting stylized and their getting smaller and fitting the view port after hover. The problem is on this part of the menu **Products > Product 1**

```css
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #39b1cc;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #51bbd2), color-stop(100%, #2d97af));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: url('images/bg.png');
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 18px 25px 21px 25px;
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.12);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #d3eced;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #32a9c3;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 45px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #d3eced;
  right: 17px;
  top: 22px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub.active > a::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a {
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  top: 60px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  font-size: 13px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  top: -4px;
  left: 20px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li > ul::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 20px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #ffffff;
  top: 11px;
  left: -4px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul::after {
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: #ffffff;
  left: auto;
  right: -4px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
  top: 120px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  top: 52px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-left: 6px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  padding-right: 6px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: 180px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 11px 25px;
  width: 180px;
  color: #777777;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
  color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #777777;
  right: 17px;
  top: 14px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #777777;
  right: auto;
  left: 17px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub.active > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-left-color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub.active > a::after,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub:hover > a::after {
  border-right-color: #333333;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>


   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <title>CSS MenuMaker</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
<html>
```

Can i stop the loading of the `li` before the hover on the menu? Or can i stylize the to be a super small before the hover and how?

Comment: i cannot replicate the `scroll` problem. Can you make a working snippet that shows your problem ? see here > https://jsfiddle.net/vm241Lve/

Comment: your question is confusing since the problem is not seen on your snippet? Or do you see it if you run your snippet?

Comment: You can see it. Just scroll down to the last link of "Sub Product". After that move the mouse out of the menu and you will see that the scroll will get more expanded.

Comment: Or switch hovers on "PRODUCTS" and "ABOUT" multiple times wile looking on the scroll bar. He is getting resized... This is annoying wile the page is bumping up when hover in this part of the menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `display:block;/display:none;` instead of `opacity:1;/opacity:0;`

```css
#cssmenu,
    #cssmenu ul,
    #cssmenu ul li,
    #cssmenu ul li a,
    #cssmenu #menu-button {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        list-style: none;
        line-height: 1;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #cssmenu:after,
    #cssmenu>ul:after {
        content: ".";
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        visibility: hidden;
        line-height: 0;
        height: 0;
    }

    #cssmenu #menu-button {
        display: none;
    }

    #cssmenu {
        width: auto;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background: #39b1cc;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #51bbd2), color-stop(100%, #2d97af));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #51bbd2 0%, #2d97af 100%);
    }

    #cssmenu>ul {
        background: url('images/bg.png');
        box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    }

    #cssmenu.align-right>ul>li {
        float: right;
    }

    #cssmenu>ul>li {
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #cssmenu.align-center>ul {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #cssmenu.align-center>ul>li {
        float: none;
    }

    #cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
        text-align: left;
    }

    #cssmenu>ul>li>a {
        padding: 18px 25px 21px 25px;
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.12);
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #d3eced;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

    #cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a,
    #cssmenu>ul>li>a:hover,
    #cssmenu>ul>li.active>a {
        color: #ffffff;
        background: #32a9c3;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    #cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a {
        padding-right: 45px;
    }

    #cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: 6px solid transparent;
        border-top-color: #d3eced;
        right: 17px;
        top: 22px;
    }

    #cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub.active>a::after,
    #cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub:hover>a {
        border-top-color: #ffffff;
    }

    #cssmenu ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        left: -9999px;
        top: 60px;
        padding-top: 6px;
        font-size: 13px;
        /* opacity: 0; */
        display: none;
        -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
        -o-transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
        transition: top 0.2s ease, opacity 0.2s ease-in;
    }

    #cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
        text-align: right;
    }

    #cssmenu>ul>li>ul::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: 5px solid transparent;
        border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
        top: -4px;
        left: 20px;
    }

    #cssmenu.align-right>ul>li>ul::after {
        left: auto;
        right: 20px;
    }

    #cssmenu ul ul ul::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: 5px solid transparent;
        border-right-color: #ffffff;
        top: 11px;
        left: -4px;
    }

    #cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul::after {
        border-right-color: transparent;
        border-left-color: #ffffff;
        left: auto;
        right: -4px;
    }

    #cssmenu>ul>li>ul {
        top: 120px;
    }

    #cssmenu>ul>li:hover>ul {
        top: 52px;
        left: 0;
        /* opacity: 1; */
        display: block;
    }

    #cssmenu.align-right>ul>li:hover>ul {
        left: auto;
        right: 0;
    }

    #cssmenu ul ul ul {
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-left: 6px;
    }

    #cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
        padding-right: 6px;
    }

    #cssmenu ul ul>li:hover>ul {
        left: 180px;
        top: 0;
        /* opacity: 1; */
        display: block;
    }

    #cssmenu.align-right ul ul>li:hover>ul {
        left: auto;
        right: 100%;
        /* opacity: 1; */
        display: block;
    }

    #cssmenu ul ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding: 11px 25px;
        width: 180px;
        color: #777777;
        background: #ffffff;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    #cssmenu ul ul li:hover>a,
    #cssmenu ul ul li.active>a {
        color: #333333;
    }

    #cssmenu ul ul li:first-child>a {
        border-top-left-radius: 3px;
        border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    }

    #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child>a {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    }

    #cssmenu>ul>li>ul::after {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
    }

    #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub>a::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border: 4px solid transparent;
        border-left-color: #777777;
        right: 17px;
        top: 14px;
    }

    #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub>a::after {
        border-left-color: transparent;
        border-right-color: #777777;
        right: auto;
        left: 17px;
    }

    #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub.active>a::after,
    #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover>a::after {
        border-left-color: #333333;
    }

    #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub.active>a::after,
    #cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub:hover>a::after {
        border-right-color: #333333;
        border-left-color: transparent;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>


   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <title>CSS MenuMaker</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
<html>
```

Other option you can use `overflow` and `height` properties in `ul` which is having lots of options in it. For eg.:-
`overflow: auto;height: 100px;`

Comment: The first option `display:block;/display:none;` is disable the animation in the menu. I'm trying to test with the second but any idea in witch part of the `ul`

Comment: The `ul` which is having lots of options in it (Sub Product, Sub Product, Sub Product etc...)